# How do you do Canvas Authentication in React application?

Tags: visualforce, single-sign-on, react, canvas-app

I am having the nodeJS+React application and now I want to embedded it in Salesforce via Canvas. I have to validate the sign request to find out authenticate users and then need to redirect users to my React application.

I put the React app URL as Canvas app URL then make the VF page to check it but It's not working. How am I achieve my requirement? Also, are there any good examples related to this?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.